# Thesis title page: how can I write my name and my supervisor's name on the same line?

Tags: titles, thesis, line

I've written my thesis title page in this simple way, but I'd like to have the words "Supervisor" and "Student" on the same line (of course one on the left and one on the right side of the page but on the same line) and similarly for "Student's name and surname" and "Supervisor's name and supervisor". I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions? Thank you

````
\thispagestyle{empty}
   \begin{center}
       \includegraphics[scale=0.5] {logo.png}\\
       \vspace{1cm}
       \Large{Name of the University}\\
       \Large{Name of the department}\\
       \vspace{.5cm}
       \normalsize{Master degree in ...}\\
       \vspace{1cm}
       \Large{Title}
   \end{center}
   \vspace{3cm}
   \begin{flushleft}
   Supervisor\\
   Supervisor's name and surname\\
   \end{flushleft}

   \begin{flushright}
   Student \\
   Student's name and surname

   \end{flushright}
   \vfill
   \begin{center}
   \vspace{2cm}
       Academic year 2019/2020
   \end{center}

    ```
````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which document class are you using? When posting code here, it's always a better idea to make it compilable: your code should begin with ``\documentclass{...}`` and end with ``\end{document}``.

Comment: use a table with 2 columns--first column=supervisor name--second column=student name--first column=left align `l`--second column=right align `r`

Comment: Ok! Sorry, I didn't know it. I'm using \documentclass{book}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tabularx` for that:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
   \begin{center}
       \includegraphics[scale=0.5] {TasmanianDevil}\\
       \vspace{1cm}
       \Large{Name of the University}\\
       \Large{Name of the department}\\
       \vspace{.5cm}
       \normalsize{Master degree in ...}\\
       \vspace{1cm}
       \Large{Title}
   \end{center}
   \vspace{3cm}
   \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
   Supervisor & Student \\
   Supervisor's name and surname & Student's name and surname
   \end{tabularx}
   \vfill
   \begin{center}
   \vspace{2cm}
       Academic year 2019/2020
   \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]